# Diff between two branches in Stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to comparing 2 branches in a Stash repository. Giving the two branches in source and destination URL paths showed no difference. But after swapping the branches (source becomes destination and destination becomes source) I see some changes. Is it the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pull request shows what would happen if you merged the source branch into the destination branch.  Usually the destination branch is an ancestor of the source branch, so you'd expect to see changes.  But you'd expect to see no changes if you swap them around - merging an ancestor into a descendant has no effect.